# Insert blank line after different lines

Tags: ex-mode, ex-command

Given file *alfa.txt*:

```
foxtrot
golf
hotel
india
juliet
```

I would like to insert a newline after lines 2 and 4. I have this command:

```
ex -sc '2pu_|4pu_|x' alfa.txt
```

However it is inserting lines after line 2 and 3, instead of 2 and 4:

```
foxtrot
golf

hotel

india
juliet
```

Comment: `:g/^\%2l\|\%4l/pu _`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example based on the comment:

```
ex -sc 'g/\v%2l|%4l/pu_' -cx alfa.txt
```

Here is a working alternative to my original command:

```
ex -sc '4pu_|2pu_|x' alfa.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

The commands are executed serially, which means that before the `4pu_` command is executed, a newline has already been added and your previous line 4 is now line 5.

There are at least three ways to solve this:

1. Start from the back. This way, previous changes do not affect later changes.
2. As suggested by Christian Brabrandt, you can add newlines based on a global command:

   ```
   :g/\v^%2l|%4l/pu _
   ```

   To understand this command, read about [`:h :global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global). *Note:* To save a keypress I've used `\v`. With `\v`, we don't need to escape the `%l` and `|`.
3. Manually add to the number(s), i.e. do

   ```
   ex -sc '2pu_|5pu_|x' alfa.txt
   ```